# Rails nested_form_for not working when using file_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, nested-forms

When using `nested_form_for` and having a `file_field` in `fields_for` I get the following error from paperclip:

**Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError in ProjectsController#create**

`No handler found for "scan.pdf"`

This is correct, because the params don't show an `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile>` object, but just the file name.

Before using `nested_form_for` it worked, it works when I uncomment the `file_field` and it also works when I build the first object for `fields_for` but this shouldn't be necessary..

My setup is as follows:

- ruby 1.9.3
- rails (3.2.8)
- paperclip (3.3.0)
- nested_form (0.3.0)

The code:

```
# @project.schemes.build
= nested_form_for @project do |f|
  = f.fields_for :schemes do |ff|
    = ff.text_field :name
    = ff.file_field :scan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generated form is not multipart and you have 2 options to solve this issue:

- specify multipart manually

  ```
  = nested_form_for @project, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|
  ```
- try using nested_form gem from the master branch which have this issue solved but not yet released

  ```
  gem 'nested_form', :github => 'ryanb/nested_form'
  ```

Comment: I'm going for the second option, which learned me that instead of `git: "url:://to.repository"` I can use `github: "name/of/repository"`.. Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: Oke, I give up, it doesn't work for me.. back to just `:git => ".."`